# Something with eigenvalue and eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\x&1&y\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ 
has three independent eigenvectors. Prove that $x+y=0$

Becasue $A$ has three independent eigenvectors, and its rank is three, so it must have three different eigenvalues right? But why if I calculate the eigenvalues of $A$, I got $1,1,-1$. There are two repeated eigenvalues why? Or I calculate the eigenvalues wrongly? And how to prove that $x+y=0$

Comment: The same eigenvalue can correspond with several orthogonal eigenvectors.

Comment: Think of an identity matrix. It has only $1$ as eigenvalue but every vector in the space is an eigenvector.

Comment: @Mico but $x+y=2$

Comment: Oh, I see. If there are n different eigenvalues, then there are n independent eigenvectors, but the inverse is not correct. Thanks.

Comment: @user10444 - Sorry, I had overlooked the main concern seems to be with the fact that the matrix has a repeated (non-zero) eigenvalue. The eigenvectors associated with repeated eigenvalue are linearly independent (and orthogonal to the eigenvector associated with the distinct, third eigenvalue), but they needn't be orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial:

$$p_A(t)=\det(tI-A)=t^2(t-1)-(t-1)=(t-1)^2(t+1)$$

Let's see what's the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $\;t=1\;$ :

$$\begin{cases}\;\;\;\;\,x_1-x_3&=0\\-xx_1-yx_3&=0\\\;\,-x_1+x_3&=0\end{cases}$$

Clearly equations $\;I,III\;$ are linearly dependent, and since the matrix is diagonalizable iff there's only one single, independient equation (i.e., iff the eigenspace's dimension is $\;2\;$) (why?), we must have

$$I\;\;:\;\; x_1=x_3\implies II\;\;:\;\;x_1(-x-y)=0\implies x+y=0$$

$$$$

Answer (score 0):

[ 0 0 1 ] [ u ]    [ w ]

[ x 1 y ] [ v ] =  [ xu + v + yw ]

[ 1 0 0 ] [ w ]    [ u ]

eigenvalue 1 leads to

u = w

(x+y)u = 0

eigenvalue -1 leads to

u=-w

If u = 0, the vectors are not independent (because the first and third
 components are 0)

So, $u\ne 0$, hence x+y=0.

Comment: I am not firm with producing matrices, perhaps someone can edit it.